# Understanding depth values in 3D point cloud

Tags: matlab, 3d, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I have problems understanding the depth (Z) value in 3D point cloud resulted from 3d sparse reconstruction like this example in MATLAB: http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/sparse-3-d-reconstruction-from-multiple-views.html

I have attached a picture showing the reconstructed 3D point cloud in the above example. I have put some datatips on the figure so we know the (x,y,z) coordinates of the points. here are my questions:

1- what does the Z value in point cloud represent? is it the distance in millimeters from the camera? if that's the case then it does not make sense based on the picture I attached since I am sure the distance of the sphere and checkerboard from the camera must be greater than 200 mm.
Or maybe it is from some reference point in space? then what is this reference point? and how can I make a 3D point cloud that the Z values indicate the distance from the camera?

2- why is there negative values for Z? what does that mean in terms of distance to the camera?

I appreciate if someone can explain.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this example the world coordinates are defined by the checkerboard. The checkerboard defines the X-Y plane, and the Z-axis points into the checkerboard, as explained in the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/gs/coordinate-systems.html):

[image]

Since your 3D points are above the checkerboard, they have negative Z-coordinates.

Answer (score -2):

Your (x,y,z) coordinates are in world units, which are completely disconnected from metric values (unless you build a scale between world and metric, there are various methods to do it). So the z value tells you about the depth of each point in world coordinates.

If you have the pose of each camera, and you multiply each point by the camera projection matrix, you will get the (x',y',z') points in camera coordinates. At that point, if z' is negative, it means it's *behind the camera*.

Comment: but I was told that if the camera calibration matrices (I mean rotation and translation) are in millimeters, then the 3D point cloud will be in millimeters as is indicated in the MATLAB example above. you can also look at the labels of the picture attached, they are all in millimeters. there is no object behind the camera. both the sphere and checkerboard are in front of the camera! so this example is wrong??

Comment: Are you using a stereo pair or a single camera? There is no way you're going to get metric reconstruction out of just vision with a single camera. You need the sensor size in mm to build the calibration matrix in some cases (it is *not* rotation and translation btw), but then you have to convert to pixels.

Comment: Yes I am using s stereo pair of course, as explained in this example (http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/sparse-3-d-reconstruction-from-multiple-views.html). I don't think you need the sensor size in case of SPARSE 3D reconstruction since the extrinsic parameters (translation) is in mm. you only need the sensor size if you are doing Dense 3D reconstruction using disparity map. correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You need "some" size (e.g. the sensor size, or the size of an object in the scene - perhaps the calibration target) to do any sort of metric reconstruction. Without that, all you world (or camera) coordinates are known only up to some unknown scale.

Comment: I have the checkerboard size (each square is 30mm). Can we go back to my main question please? how can I get the distance from the camera from this 3D point cloud, and what does the negative Z mean?

Comment: anybody else can answer my question?

Comment: @CV_passionate, I hope it is not too late. :)